# VueJS get image from Firebase Storage downloadURL

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, firebase-storage

Im currently trying to show images that I stored in Firebase storage in an image slider. When I try to use: `v-bind:content="image.downloadUrl"` it shows the actual downloadUrl string, but it doesn't download the image.

I've used a similar approach with Angular and then I'm able to get the image downloaded from the URL, does anyone know how I can get the image in VueJS?

Code:

`<vueper-slides>
  <vueper-slide v-for="image in house.images2" v-bind:key="image.downloadUrl" v-bind:content="image.downloadUrl"> </vueper-slide>
</vueper-slides>`

Should I declare the field in a different way?

I've tried with:

`v-bind:key="{{image.downloadUrl}}"`
 `v-bind:key="'{image.downloadUrl}"`

but that also doesn't work.

Comment: Did you tried `:image="image.downloadUrl"` ? See https://antoniandre.github.io/vueper-slides/#vueper-slide--settings

Comment: I completely missed that, it works. Thank you!